# Horizontal Ball Rod Connection Broken

Tags: plumbing, repair, sink

I hope my terminology makes sense.

My sink was draining slowly so I tried to remove the horizontal ball rod, and it was stuck tightly. Using a wrench I got it free but the connection to the sink's drain was so rusted it broke off inside of the horizonal ball rod's metal nut(unsure if this correct name). SO I think I have to either buy a new metal drain under the sink and horizontal ball rod kit, or is there some way I could jury rig it? I was considering using epoxy to make it serviceable for now. Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Take apart the sink drain and take the parts to the hardware store for a new one.  This happens all the time and what is super annoying is the companies that make the stoppers are constantly changing the dimensions so it's not like you can just go buy the part that broke and replace it, you have to buy a complete new assembly.  They make more money that way.

Comment: If you can removed it without having a leak, can replaced with plain rubber drain stopper.  if this is what the problem was.  Might have to get hand wet, to use it.

Comment: Thanks guys! SO if dimensions change does that mean the sink itself has to be replaced??

Comment: I have found repair parts but take Teds advice and take it with you so you will be sure it will fit ether a repair part or complete replacement (not as bad as an entire sink).

Answer (score 0):

The ball rod is what allows the drain stopper to open and close. It is installed in the back of the sink drain just below the sink drain and held in place by a nut.

You can purchase a new lever at any supply or hardware store. They are all standard in size. the part comes with a lift rod connected to ball, a rubber washer and a nut.

If the threads on the drain (that the nut tightens too) have been damaged you will need to replace the entire drain section.